# Android R parameter refers to another unknown R

Tags: java, android

I have few .java files in my android project. I use R class several times in them.

However, in one file, I can't get it to work. When I use for example `R.array.contextList` (contexList array is in my generated R class) it says that `contextList cannot be resolved or is not a field`. When I press `ctrl+space` it suggests me arrays like `emailAdressTypes` or `postalAddressTypes`... I have never seen those arrays. What's happening? Thanks

PS: I have cleaned my project several times and fixed errors in project several times.

Comment: Which version of the Android SDK are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the imports.. if it has something like

> android.R;

remove it and import your project's R.java

[The documentation of android.R](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R), this will explain where those things came from.

Comment: damn, that's it. I don't like eclipse :/ Thanks a lot